# Using Array From Another class Show Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, arrays, clone

I'm trying yo use an array that is created in one class and using `Clone()` To clone it into another class by triggering a method but its throwing a null pointer exception

```
int[] mat[];
int N; 
int SRN;
int K;
int send[][];
Generate()
{ 

}
Generate(int N, int K) 
{ 
    this.N = N; 
    this.K = K; 

    // Compute square root of N 
    Double SRNd = Math.sqrt(N); 
    SRN = SRNd.intValue();

    mat = new int[N][N];
}

public int[][] SendAry()
{
    return send.clone();
}
```

and call this method from another class and string it in an array

```
    Generate ARY=new Generate();
    int Values[][]=ARY.SendAry();
```

Comment: Looks like `send` is not being created.  You need to add the line `send = new int[a number][another number]` in your constructor.

Comment: `send` is always null, cause you never initialize it

Comment: You assign to `mat` but then try to clone `send`.  No worky.

Comment: Your `send` array is never initialized, so will be null when you try to access it in the `SendAry` method. Also, you pretty much break every possible Java coding convention there is in your snippet... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array send is not initialized so it is null. You can initialize it using many ways.
The simplest way is `int send[][] = new int[<size>][<size>];` the `<size>` is the size you want the array to have.
You can see more about initializing arrays from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-array)

Comment: Thanks for the replay but the nullpointexception is solved but the array is still empty. not null but zeros even if i point it directly with an object

Comment: what do you want to have?

Comment: This is a program to create a sudoku puzzle the array is in generate class and its working fine if i print it directly from that class it works fine but im trying to use that array and print it using an interface using panels and buttons and all that but as soon as i clone it or even directly point to the array in the class using an object its empty now like zeros all the way

Comment: the whole array is full of zeros by default. You can change them using a loop.

Comment: yeah the method runs...Changes the values....when i print it in the same class it works. but if print it in another class its zeros

Comment: can I see what code you used?

Comment: I figured it out. i was asking for the array before a method worked on it so thats why it was showing up as Zero. thanks for the help about initializing array that actually really helped